# Possible to make donation to SuperUser.com?

Tags: windows, open-source

I feel like this community is something that's definitely worth supporting.

Is it possible for me to make a donation? Is it possible through PayPal?

Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be on SE Meta.

Comment: @Chenmunka - you should have instead voted to *migrate* it to Meta, rather than provide a custom reason.

Comment: That wasn't one of the migration destinations offered.  Otherwise I would have done.

Comment: Stack Exchange doesn’t need the money.